# MVC Multiple File Upload with Additional Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have been able to post multiple files to my controller successfully by follwing the following:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

However, 
I am trying to also include some information with each file uploaded that the user must enter e.g A title and version

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/EWOCUXIS/1/edit) to maybe show what I am trying to achieve.

Here is what I have currently come up with for dealing with it [in this way](http://pastebin.com/62u0zqQw).

This doesn't seem like the correct way as I am used to passing models to the controller?
Another issue with this is if the user adds three file uploads but only selects 2 files, then it will be out of sync.

I have done a bit of searching and couldn't seem to find an example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create 2 ViewModels

```
public class NewViewModel 
{
    // list of files with additional data
    public List<UploadItem> UploadItems { get; set; }

    public string AnotherPropForView { get; set; }
}

public class UploadItem
{
    // your additional data
    public string CustomProp1  { get; set; }
    public string CustomProp2  { get; set; }
    // file
    public HttpPostedFileBase UpFile { get; set; }
}
```

Create controller. One action for display empty form and second for process data from view.

```
public class SomeController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Create() 
    {
      NewViewModel model = new NewViewModel
      {
         // inicialize list
         UploadItems = new List<UploadItems> 
         {
            // inicialize empty objects ( if you want to have 2 file fields with additional data)
            // or inicialize only one object and another fields add by Javascript
            new UploadItem {},
            new UploadItem {},
         }
      }
      return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(NewViewModel model) 
    {
        // if (ModelState.IsValid) etc...
        foreach (var uploadItem in model.UploadItems)
        {
            // work with file and additional data
            var file = uploadItem.UpFile;
            var prop1 = uploadItem.CustomProp1;
            // file.SaveAs("/some/where"); atc ...
        }

        // return some view...
    }
}
```

And create view

```
@model Path.To.NewViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Some", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@* Print all inicialized upload items *@
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UploadItems.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadItems[@i].CustomProp1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadItems[@i].CustomProp2)
    <input type="file" id="UploadItems[@i].UpFile" name="UploadItems[@i].UpFile" />
  }

<button name="Action" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn">Save</button>
}
```

You can use Javascript for dynamic adding Uploaditem to form - you have to generate right index to name and ID property in inputs

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have it working :D
Only issue I have left is using DataAnnotations in the model? Any Ideas?

Comment: You can use DataAnnotations in ViewModel. For example in UploadItem class
[Display(Name = "Name for CustomProp1")]
public string CustomProp1  { get; set; }